# Поиск определенной даты в БД через sql запрос из C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net, asp.net-webforms

Имеется переменная со значением даты `string id = Session["SelectedDate"].ToString();`
Далее прописываю селект по этой дате из БД:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from ViewFlights where DateOut = " + id, con);
```

Далее происходит ошибка:

> Конфликт типов операндов: date несовместим с int

Прошу помощи с двумя вопросами:

1. как привести типы?
2. как проверить пустой запрос приходит или
   нет?

Comment: В каком виде хранится "SelectedDate"?  Для конвертации используйте DateTime.Parse(id)

Comment: Какой формат поля в БД `DateOut`?

Comment: Формат поля в БД: date

Comment: в SelectedDate строка типа dd/MM/yyyy

Comment: зачем вы делаете `.ToString()` строке?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не используйте конкатенацию строк, `string.Format` или интерполяцию при работе с SQL-запросами! Это мало того что создает подобные проблемы с форматом - так еще и подвержено SQL-инъекциям.

Вот правильный способ:

```
var date = (DateTime)Session["SelectedDate"];
// Если там лежит не дата - ее надо сначала преобразовать к дате:
// var date = DateTime.ParseExact((string)Session["SelectedDate"], "dd/MM/yyyy");
// Но это плохой вариант - парсить дату желательно еще до того как она попадет в сессию!

var con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
con.Open();

var cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from ViewFlights where DateOut = @date", con);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.Date).Value = date;
```

Comment: спасибо, работает, только стоило добавить перед парсом: `CultureInfo us = new CultureInfo("en-US");` и добавить провайдера "us" в парс.